# Why does POST work on local Firebase server, but not on the deployed server?

Tags: node.js, firebase, http-post, http-get, formidable

I thought I had trouble with uploading files with to Google Cloud Storage (GCS), but it looks like there might be something completely different that is wrong. (I am not going to post any code here at the moment because I do not know if it is relevant. I will add code if we find something that could help.)

The situation is this:

- I am POSTing (with `fetch`, using `FormData`) to a Firebase server.
- The server decodes the post with `Formidable`.
- There are (currently) no `<input type="file"...>` in the form, but this makes no difference.
- This works on the local Firebase server, but not on the deployed server.
- The deployed server times out.

If I instead of `POST` use `GET` the deployed server does not time out.

I have no idea what could be going on here. Ideas?

Comment: without code, we can only speculate.

Comment: @marcos That depends on what you know. Please consider to give your example of code that could make a difference here. If you know something of that kind. (I don't. That is why I'm asking. However there are many things I do not know about FormData and POST and exactly how it is handled. I just use the standard handling - to avoid problems.)

Comment: The code is always relevant.

Comment: @DougStevenson I do not think so. I am more asking for knowledge about standards here. And what can go wrong with them.